# create a full many-2-many matrix

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a 2 tables with a many-2-many relationship:
tableA (ida, valA)
tableB (idb, valB)
tableAB (ida, idb)

I need one query that should return in every tupple:
(ida, idb, 0/1 if related or not)

Here is some input / output example:
**tableA**

```
ida   valA
1     b
2     s
3     l
```

**tableB**

```
idb   valB
11    aaa
22    bbb
33    ccc
```

**tableAB**

```
ida   idb
1     11
2     33
```

Expected results:

```
ida      idb      is_exists
1        11       1
2        11       0
1        33       0
2        33       1
```

Note that I don't need permutations which are always 0, for example ida=3 or idb=22
this is because it means that in a matrix the whole row or column is 0 (this shows that the row has no relation whatsoever with the other table)

```
   \ ida |     |     |  
idb \    |  1  |  2  |  3
---------------------------
11       |  1  |  0  |  0
---------------------------
22       |  0  |  0  |  0
---------------------------
33       |  0  |  1  |  0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is a driving table that has all possible pairs.  One way to get this is from TableA and TableB, using a cross join:

```
select allAB.aid, allAB.bid, max(case when ab.aid is not null then 1 else 0 end) as HasPair
from (select distinct a.id as aid, b.id as bid
      from TableA a cross join
           TableB b
     ) as allAB left outer join
     TableAB ab
     on allAB.aid = ab.aid and
        allAB.bid = ab.bid
group by allAB.aid, allAB.bid
```

After that, the query just summarizes and determines whether there is a matching record in TableAB.

Comment: Why is the `max()` application needed around the `case` statement?

Comment: Because ab.id is not included in the group by clause.  This produces one row per pair.

Comment: This gives also records which have no relationship (see the note in my question). Anyway if I create allAB as the cross join of itself (selecting once only the distinct ida and second only the distinct idb) it works great!

Comment: I would have upvoted but I still can't. So, **people of the world ! if you read this great answer please upvote it !!!**